# Dynamically setting y-axis domain in ggvis+shiny depending on input

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am trying to plot 4 different graphs on the same page, using shiny+ggvis. The sidebar has 3 `selectizeInput` controls where one sets the parameters and a button which triggers the plotting. All data is fetched from a mysql database, and the selectize inputs are also generated based on the content of the database (each one depends on the previous).

Now, I would like to add a checkbox, which, when ticked, would make all 4 plots to have the same maximum. However, when I try to do that, I get something like:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
>     Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

What should I do to get the same maximums (which I will not know a priori until I get the filtered data, that is, maximums are data dependent) on all plots?

The skeleton of my code follows:

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(2,
      wellPanel(
        selectizeInput('ci_select', '1. Instance:', choices = cis,
                       options = list(
                         placeholder = 'Please select a instance below',
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                       )),
        ## two more selectizeInput, for 'runid_select' and 'setup_select'
        ...
        checkboxInput('maximums', 'Use same maximum', TRUE),
        actionButton("go_button", "Plot"))),

    column(10,
           fluidRow(
             column(6, ggvisOutput('tl')),
             column(6, ggvisOutput('tr'))),
           fluidRow(
             column(6, ggvisOutput('bl')),
             column(6, ggvisOutput('br')))))))
```

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) {
  observe({
    if (input$ci_select != "") {
      # ... query db and fill runids
      updateSelectInput(session, "runid_select", choices = runids)
    }
  })
  # ... similar to the above for runid and setup

  plot_data <- reactive({
    input$go_button
    ci <- isolate(input$ci_select)
    # ... some checks ...
    # ... extract values from input$setup in num_machines, num_volumes, vol_size ...

    r <- data %>%
      filter(ci == local(ci), runid == local(runid)) %>%
      # ... and a lot of other filtering
      collect()
  })

  max_read_bandwidth <- reactive({
      maxx <- read_data %>% summarise(maxx=max(read_bandwidth))
      maxx[1]$maxx
  })
  max_write_bandwidth <- reactive({
      maxx <- read_data %>% summarise(maxx=max(write_bandwidth))
      maxx[1]$maxx
  })
  max_bandwidth <- reactive({
      max(max_read_bandwidth, max_write_bandwidth)
  })

  plot_data %>%
       filter(fio_type=='read') %>%
       ggvis(~fio_bs, ~read_bandwidth) %>%
       layer_points() %>%
       scale_numeric("y", domain=c(0, ifelse(input$maximums, max_bandwidth(), max_read_bandwidth()))) %>%
       bind_shiny("tl")

  plot_data %>%
       filter(fio_type=='randread') %>%
       ggvis(~fio_bs, ~read_bandwidth) %>%
       layer_points() %>%
       scale_numeric("y", domain=c(0, ifelse(input$maximums, max_bandwidth(), max_read_bandwidth()))) %>%
       bind_shiny("tr")
```